# Error in gcloud python flask app for importing keras and opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tensorflow, keras

Getting error while deploying my flask app to Gcloud app engine it failed to import tensorflow in keras and python-opencv lib here is error,

opencv-

```
   File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
        import cv2
   File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        from .cv2 import *
   ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

& tensorflow-

```
File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    from keras.models import load_model

File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

note:- same problem occurs in heroku also.